# Prove a set is connected and is a connected component

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a Hausdorff and compact space, given $x \in X$ we consider the collection $\mathcal{C}= \{C_i\}$ of all the closed and open subsets $C_i$ such that $x \in C_i$. Prove that $C = \cap C_i$ is connected. Prove that $C$ is the connected component of $x$ in $X$.

I tried this, but I am not sure it is right as I did not use X being Hausdorff and compact.
Given $\{U,V\}$ such that $C= U \sqcup V$, then $U = C \cap X-V$, w.l.o.g $x \in U$, so $U$ is an open and closed (intersection of closed subsets) subset. Therefore, $C \subset U$ , so $V = \emptyset$  #

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Why should $U$ be open? (In $X$; it's of course relatively open in $C$.)

Comment: True! I am going to think about it...

Comment: I also realised Haussdorf + compact $\implies$ T4, if it helps

Comment: Not "$=$". But "$\implies$".